# awk to print of column headers if field has dot in it

Tags: awk

In the `tab-delimited` `file` below I am trying to use `awk` to print out the headers of the fields if they contain a single `.` (dot). The other fields should not contain a `.` and I am going to use another `awk` to detect there data type (either alpha or integer --- could be a decimal). The below seems close but not working as expected.  Thank you :).

**file**

```
Index   HGMD    Sanger  Classification     Pop
1   .   .   VUS     .36
```

**awk**

```
awk -F'\t' '$2 && $3 ~ /./ && FNR == 1 {printf "dot detected in fields: ORS $0"}' file
Index   HGMD    Sanger  Classification
```

**desired output**

```
dot detected in fields: HGMD, Sanger
```

Comment: `.36` is a single record or two records?

Comment: sorry, that is two records. Basically the `.` will be by itself.... it represents a null value.  The .36 is a decimal that represents `36%`.  Thank you :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want the headers of the columns that have a single dot on any line (`HGMD` and `Sanger` here):

```
Index   HGMD    Sanger  Classification  Pop
1       .       2       VUS     .36
1       .       .       VUS     .36
```

One solution would be:

```
awk -F'\t' 'NR==1 {for (i=0 ; i <= NF ; i++) headers[i] = $i; }     # 1
    NR!=1 {for (i=0 ; i <= NF ; i++) if ($i == ".") dots[i] = 1}    # 2
    END { printf "Dots in fields: ";                            
         for (x in headers) if (dots[x]) printf "%s ", headers[x];  # 3
         printf "\n"
}  ' file
```

(1) collect the headers from the first input line to array `headers`. 
(2) On other input lines, compare the value to a single dot, and set the entry in array `dots` to record any found dots.
(3) Finally, print out headers of the columns with `dots[i]` set.

Output is `Dots in fields: HGMD Sanger`, i.e. they are only listed once.

---

The dot matches any character in a regex, so `$3 ~ /./` in your snippet would be true if field 3 contained any character. Also, `$2 && $3 ~ ...` would first test field 2 for truthiness (an empty string is falsy), and then do the match on field 3.

Answer (score 1):

Use an `Awk` as below

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t"}NR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) header[i]=$i}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if (match($i,/^\.$/)) { print header[i] } } }' file
HGMD
Sanger
```

The idea is to get the header information from the first line *hashed* by index `1..n` and when processing the actual lines, if the `.` is encountered, get the hashed value from the array and print it.

Comment: Instead of using `match` maybe `if ($i == ".") ...` is a bit simpler.

Comment: Thank you both for the help and explanations :).

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '
NR==1 { split($0,hdr); next }
{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        if ($i != ".") {
            delete hdr[i]
        }
    }
}
END {
    printf "dot detected in fields"
    for (i in hdr) {
        printf "%s %s", (c++?",":":"), hdr[i]
    }
    print ""
}
' file
dot detected in fields: HGMD, Sanger
```